# One entity to many entities symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

With doctrine on symfony, looking to an entity linked to multiple entities on a single remaining column.
For example :

Entity **engine** extend two entities

- Entity **plane**
- Entity **car**

[image: one entity to many entities]

I want to use a single column in engine, because I'm having a very large number of linked table.

I can not find what is the best practice in this kind of scheme.
This is possible? how ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can do this with ["Class Table Inheritance"](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). Though you would need to introduce a common parent type. Possibly `abstract class Vehicle {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with '[Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)'. Your code will look like this:

```
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"car" = "Car", "plane" = "Plane"})
 */
class Vehicle
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Plane extends Vehicle
{
    // ...
}


/** @Entity */
class Car extends Vehicle
{
    // ...
}
```

This solves your problem of having only one foreign key on your Engine table. It also helps you have a more clear code when you have other 'shared' properties (for example a date of manufacture)